# Android: Fixed size ScrollView not scrolling/scrolling weird

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with a fixed size `scrollview` that i'm trying to make. I've read many questions that are similar (but not equal) to mine here in StackOverflow and other sites and none of the answers have helped me, so I decided to ask my own question.

Basically, i want a fixed size `scrollview` with different controls inside. The basic one would be a `textview` of a dynamically changing size inside it. When I change the text of the `textview` and it is bigger than the `scrollview`, the scrollbars flash quickly, as they should, indicating that I can scroll but no matter how many times I swipe my finger, it doesn't scroll. Then I tried swiping with two or three fingers and sometimes (only a counted number of times) it scrolls.

I have tried many different approaches to this, like changing the `textview` to an `edittext` with focusable = false so it doesn't give the user chance to edit the text; or putting the textview alone in the scrollview, or wrapping it in linearlayouts, relative layouts etc. and it still doesnt scroll.

Below is the code as it is today. This scrollview is inside a vertical linearlayout along with other controls that I'm not putting 'cause of the length, but if someone needs it, I'll put it. I would appreciate very much if someone can point to my problem or help me solving this.

XML:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollFifthHorizontalLineDetails"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rrrr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtlblPlaceDetails"
                android:layout_width="302dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/placedescriptionbg"
                android:text="@string/null_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

the line in which I populate the TextView:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlblPlaceDetails)).setText(mJsonOb.getString("placeDescription"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an Android app I was developing a few months back. I got around the scrolling problem by increasing the layout width for the scroll view. In the editor you can actually drag the RHS of the scroll view to exceed the visible area. I think I set the android:layout_width to about 1024.